# Why don't I see Settings results when using Windows 8.1 smart search?

Tags: windows-8.1

When using smart search in my new Windows 8.1 Pro machine I'm not getting results as expected. Currently when I hit the Start button and begin typing "programs and", I would expect to see "Programs and Features" in the search results since it's searching "Everywhere". If I select "Settings" in the search drop down after having typed "programs and", I do see Programs and Features listed. This doesn't make sense to me as I would expect "Everything" to include results from "Settings" as well.

Comment: I have the same issue with my user profile. I've read suggestions to delete the Windows Search cache in disk and restart the Indexing service, as well as rebuild the user profile. In both cases that hasn't helped me, but you might want to try them.

Comment: The odd thing is that on my home machine it works as expected, but on my work machine (both are 8.1) it behaves as I've described above. I wonder if it could be related to a group policy or something maybe?

Comment: A recent Windows update + reboot cycle has resolved the problem on my affected user profile. The last updates I see in my history are just antivirus definition updates and the Malicious Software Removal Tool. My issue went away with no explanation! Good luck